# Ruby on Rails respond_with and image formats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, rendering, mime-types

I have a controller that responds_to html and png ( I load the image dynamically and render it as text ). That makes the controller code messy and today I found respond_with, which looks very cool, but I can't found out how to make it work with formats, different than html, json and xml ( like the png )

I expected that this would work, but it stills tries to find a template file and ignores my method :(

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  def to_png
    File.read("some_file.png")
  end
end
```

**controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :png

  # GET /users/1
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_with(@user)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add in file `[YOUR_APP]/config/initializers/mime_types.rb`:

```
Mime::Type.register "image/png", :png
```

and restart your application

Answer (score 1):

> if you need to use a MIME type which isn’t supported by default, you
>   can register your own handlers in environment.rb as follows.
>
> `Mime::Type.register "image/jpg", :jpg`

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to

in environment.rb

```
Mime::Type.register "image/png", :png
```

then

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.png do
      #do stuff here
   end
end
```

or

```
respond_with @user do |format|
   format.png do
      #do stuff here
   end
end
```

Comment: I tried the Mime type registration but it still gives me "template is missing"

I know that respond_to and then format.png will work, because it is currently like this but I was hoping that it can be moved in the model like to_json and to_xml so that the controller can only call respond_with